# Let a be a real number and suppose that

Tags: calculus

$f(x)= 2ax+5$ if $x>2$
$f(x)= x^2-ax+6a$ if $x\le2$

For which value of $a$, if any, will f be continuous at $x=2$?

I was just wondering if I approached it correctly?

$2ax+5=x^2-ax+6a$

$2a(2)+5=(2)^2-a(2)+6a$

$4a+5=4-2a+6a$

$5-4=4a-4a$

$1=0$

Therfore $f$ isnt continuous at $x=2.$

Thanks

Comment: I have edited your question. You can adjusted it if you don't like.

Comment: Thanks!It looks better than before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. If a function is continuous at some point $x_0$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to x_0^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to x_0^-}f(x)$.

Since $\lim_{x\to 2^+}f(x)=4+4a\not=5+4a=\lim_{x\to 2^-}f(x)$, then this function is not continuous at $x=2$.

Answer (score 2):

$f$ is continuous at $2$ iff

$$f(2)=4+4a=\lim_{x\to 2^-}f(x)=4a+5$$
which's impossible. Hence $f$ isn't continuous at $2$ for every $a\in\Bbb R$.